# The Syntax to call a Google Cloud Function from another Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a Google Cloud Function with HTTP trigger that call another function (example: changeString). I know that I can include the function changeString in index.js. However, I want to reuse changeString so others Google Cloud Functions can call it.

```
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
var result = changeString(req.body.string);
res.send(result);
};
```

I know that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784000/calling-a-cloud-function-from-another-cloud-function), but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Basically, I just want to know the syntax to call a function from another function in Google Cloud Function.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this myself and I think the answer is that you *don’t* call the function. Instead, you should send a payload to the PubSub service from your HTTP Cloud Function. A secondary Cloud Function subscribes to the PubSub topic and consumes the payload (which is Base64 encoded).

Answer (score -1):

As @user3158158 brings out, you would publish a message to a Pub/Sub service.  This is highlighted here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#publishing_a_message_from_within_a_function

I shows the sample syntax at the above link, I needed to do the same thing today.

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.