# How to call Firebase Callable Functions with HTTP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, http-get

I realised that the new [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) can still be called as if they were [HTTP events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), i.e. they can still be reached under `http://us-central1-$projectname.cloudfunctions.net/$functionname`. When doing that I receive an error message in my *Cloud Functions Log*:

```
Request has invalid method. GET
```

This means that *HTTP-GET* does not work, but is there a way to call the functions? Maybe they are using *HTTP-CONNECT*.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

EDIT: The details of the protocol have been [formally documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) now.

HTTPS Callable functions must be called using the `POST` method, the `Content-Type` must be `application/json` or `application/json; charset=utf-8`, and the body must contain a field called `data` for the data to be passed to the method.

Example body:

```
{
    "data": {
        "aString": "some string",
        "anInt": 57,
        "aFloat": 1.23
    }
}
```

If you are calling a function by creating your own http request, you may find it more flexible to use a regular HTTPS function instead.

Comment: For a simple example using `axios`, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73801218/6002078

Answer (score 16):

You can use Firebase CLI `firebase functions:shell` to invoke `onCall(..)` functions.

A significant bonus with this approach is that from the shell you can run the functions available in your local env. - *Firestore calls, etc* - without having to actually deploy those functions to the cloud project.

Steps:

1. Run cmd: `firebase functions:shell`

- This will give you the prompt `firebase >`

2. At the prompt call the func, and pass empty body if no params

- **firebase >** `someFuncAbc({})`

Thanks to answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051894/2162226

Yes, this answer deviates from the OP that requests how to do this with HTTP .. but adding here as an alternate way to make the calls simply from the CLI, without having to set HTTP headers, set up the HTTP client like `curl` or *Postman*, etc.