# Firebase CLI: How to send body in POST request?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been able to attach the body of a POST request in Firebase CLI before, but the documentation lacks any examples of how to do it again.

Example:

I try:

```
myFunction.post({body: {...}})
```

But receive the following error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object
```

I would like to access the data passed via `req.body`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49692155/7596193)

In my case, I would do:

```
myFunction.post().json({...})
```