# How can I prevent "Bad request" when calling Firebase's `.onCall()` method?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've just upgraded to using Firebase Cloud Functions v1.x. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49476648/628699)

> Callable functions are exactly the same as HTTP functions

With that in mind, I've tried to convert my pre-1.x mock-code:

```
export const myHttpAction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await myHttpActionWorker(req.body);
    return res.send({ status: 'OK' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ status: 'Server error' });
  }
});
```

to the following:

```
export const myHttpAction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log(context.auth);
  try {
    const result = await myHttpActionWorker(data);
    return { status: 'OK' };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return { status: 'Server error' };
  }
});
```

But upon submission to my endpoint, `/myHttpAction`, with the same data that I used in pre-1.x, I get the following back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "message": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why the request is "bad" since it's exactly the same and Callable functions are "exactly the same". Any idea what gives?

My package.json specifies `"firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what was meant by "exactly the same" (and omitting the entire remainder of the answer!).  They're the same in terms of security (as the original question was asking), because a callable function **is** an HTTP function, with extra stuff going on behind the scenes that managed by the callable client SDK.  The answer lists out those differences.  Those differences don't have any effect on security.  But you can't simply swap in a callable for an HTTP function and expect everything to be the same for existing callers.

If you want to invoke a callable function without using the client SDK, you'll have to follow its protocol specification.  The documentation on that is forthcoming, but you can get the basics here:

[How to call Firebase Callable Functions with HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476231/how-to-call-firebase-callable-functions-with-http)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Didn't mean to take you out of context there, was truly just a misunderstanding of what you meant. Wrapping the POST's body in `data` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: No worries, glad you got what you needed.