# Callable Function from another cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hey guys I have a *Callable Function* on my CloudFire that gets triggered by the Front-end. That's fine, but would it be possible to call that function from another Cloud Function? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to directly invoke a callable from another function, since there is no provided nodejs client library for callables.  If you're writing code that doesn't have a library, you would have to implement the client side of the callable spec as detailed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

An easier solution would be to simply refactor the callable function and put its work into another JavaScript function that can be directly called by the other function as described here: [Calling a Cloud Function from another Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784000/calling-a-cloud-function-from-another-cloud-function)